# Running yeoman scaffolded project in a different location or another computer?

Tags: git, web-applications, npm, gulp, yeoman

I'll preface this by saying that I am very new to front-end development, so I'm still trying to figure things out.

I used yeoman to scaffold out a project using the gulp-angular generator, which uses angularJS, gulp, bower, and several other (hopefully not as important) things as well.

After working on my application for the past few weeks, I finally have a version that I want to show other people, however, when I push my project up to github, it doesn't include many of the packages (node modules, bower components) that it needs to run correctly on someone else's machine. I assume this is intended behavior, but then how would someone else be able to view this website using these files?

The only way I ever get this to display in my browser is using gulp serve, and I don't know how to view it without using gulp. Is there a way to look at this without using gulp? Or will any other machine that it is used on need to re-download all gulp/bower components?

Additionally, could I have possibly messed up in what I'm pushing up to github? Do I need to enable something so that all of these components are pushed up as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, this is the expected behavior : not to include the dependencies source files.

In your `README.md` file, you should explain that after cloning, users, should run `npm install` and `bower install` and to see the site in dev, run `gulp serve`.

If you want to distribute your website, run `gulp build`, it will bundle your site ready for distribution in a `build/` folder. From there, simply upload the `dist/` folder via ftp (or any other means - github pages for example if you're on github).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much! Not nearly as complicated as I'd thought.